# C - raw print all non-printable characters in a string with printf

Tags: c, printf

If I have a  `char* s`and I'm printing it with printf like so:

```
printf("%s\n", s);
```

How can I force `printf` to print the non-printable characters (as something other than question marks, which I think is the default)? Like if one were to use `ls --literal`, how does it do what it does?

I know about `isprint()` but am not sure where to go from there.

Comment: You can't, you have to use a loop.

Comment: The easiest solution is to parse `s` before sending it to `printf` and check each char if it is `< 0x20` or `> 0x7e` (less than `space` of greater than `~`) and manually substitute an acceptable char in their place.

Comment: Iterate through your string, call [`isprint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isprint) to see if the char is printable. If not, substitute your own notation.

Comment: What do you want the non printable characters to be printed as? @ZoffDino `isprint()` returns `0` for white space characters.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I was originally thinking about doing something like that, but I was wondering what the system would typically do if you were to write one of these non-printables to a file or something. i.e. if I wanted to raw print it the way it is printed usually, as opposed to printf's solution of printing ? instead.

Comment: @user3475234 If you open the file in binary mode it will be fine. Use `fwrite()` instead of `fprintf()` to write to it of course.

Comment: @user3475234, your printable chars have ascii values between `0x20` (30 decimal) and `0x7e` (126 decimal). A char (actually unsigned char cast to int) can have a value from `0-255` for single byte values and any value greater than 255 for multibyte chars. As iharob says, if you write byte-by-byte with `fputc` or the like or with `fwrite`, the file won't care what the value is as it is already limited by type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a short example collecting your options from the comments earlier, you can either use a simple loop without including `ctype.h` or use `isprint()` checking the return if you do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void) {

    char s[] = "some string w/non-printables";
    char *p = s;
    char sub = '*';

    /* without including <ctype.h> */
    for (; *p; p++)
        if (*p < ' ' || *p > '~')
            *p = sub;

    p = s;
    /* including <ctype.h> */
    for (; *p; p++)
        if (isprint(*p) == 0)
            *p = sub;

    printf ("%s\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

Which simply substitutes an asterisk `'*'` if a non-printable character is encountered.

**Note:** `printf` is capable of correctly printing multi-byte characters in a string if your `LOCALE` and charset are properly set **and** the font set you are using includes the requested characters. If you are using windows, this becomes a bit more difficult given the wider variation in terminals and charsets used. You can probably easily check by printing `printf ("It is 25° outside.\n");` which if your terminal and font are set as discussed above would print correctly despite `'°'` being a multi-byte character.